# Jest - Next.js - Unexpected token error inside jest node-modules

Tags: javascript, next.js, jestjs

I installed jest with the following command on my next js project

```
npm i --save-dev jest @testing-library/react @testing-library/jest-dom jest-environment-jsdom
```

then added jest.config.json file with the below code

```
const nextJest = require("next/jest");
const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  dir: "./",
});
const customJestConfig = {
  moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", "<rootDir>/"],
  testEnvironment: "jest-environment-jsdom",
};
module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig);
```

Now, when I run 'npm test', I get the following error

> Test suite failed to run
>
> D:\my-project\node_modules\@jest\reporters\build\GitHubActionsReporter.js:67
>
> ```
>   #getMessageDetails(failureMessage, config) {
>                     ^
> ```
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('
>
> at Object. (node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/index.js:75:3)

I've tried a lot of solutions, updating the config file, adding babel plugins, none worked. And I haven't found any mention of this error online. What is the issue here?

My dev-dependencies versions -

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
  "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
  "eslint": "8.14.0",
  "eslint-config-next": "12.1.5",
  "jest": "^29.0.3",
  "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.0.3"
}
```

Comment: What version of Node are you using?

Comment: Ah, yes. thank you. I was using 14.4.0, switched to latest and above error got resolved.

Comment: Yes, private methods with the `#` syntax need at least 14.6 per https://node.green/#ES2022-features-private-class-methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by jonrsharpe, the fix is to make sure you have an updated version of node installed.
This issue isn't limited to using Jest with a Next.js solution, but also applies to Jest being used with React/VanillaJs/etc